# Can RAW -> DNG convertion harm image data?

Tags: sigma, foveon

I tried Adobe DNG Converter with X3F files produced by Sigma DP1x and everything seemed fine until a couple of files I found with the same symptoms:

(OK) Sigma Photo Pro (.X3F -> .JPEG): https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/25407/19108934.4e/0_103e2a_bc0205a1_orig

(BAD) Adobe DNG converter (.X3F -> .DNG -> .JPEG): https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/66529/19108934.4e/0_103e1b_88260a06_orig

---

1. The resulting (after Adobe AND Converter) DNG files was converted to JPEG using "darktable" and "rawtherapee" linux tools with the same red/green issue.
2. Sigma Photo Pro is a "reference" tool: a proprietary Sigma software shipped with camera.
3. I used default settings in "darktable"/"rawtherapee" software.

Comment: "Can RAW -> DNG convertion harm image data?" - yes, it was shown that Adobe DNG Converter may resample data in certain cases. However, I have seen no another evidence of something similar to what you expirienced.

Comment: Might be a problem with profile. You might want to find an input profile for DP1x and set it as input profile manually.

Comment: I would use SPP to convert the X3F to tiff and then use the resulting files in your other software of your choice. (this is what I did when I owned a DP1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any application can have a bug, misconfiguration or hit a problem, apps that do image conversions are no different; that appears to be what you've encountered here.

There's no huge benefit to converting raw files to DNG, any type of conversion (even one billed as lossless) has to modify the content in some way (or why bother with it?)  so the best thing to do is avoid conversions where there is no need to do them.

The best thing to do now would be restore the raw files from your backup, ditch the DNG files and not to worry about DNG conversion in future.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a degradation it can't reasonably go that far because of DNG conversion. i've never converted my RAWs to DNG myself though I'm thinking of it (as soon as my photo software will manage DNG files) but from what I read you have several options amongst others a lossy or lossless conversion and in the later no pixel will be touched.
Now it is not about RAWs but I already met a similar situation with raster images on some software. The thing was the software wasn't rendering the picture correctly.